# AVSpeechSynthesizer output as file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, avspeechsynthesizer

AVSpeechSynthesizer has a fairly simple API, which doesn't have support for saving to an audio file built-in.

I'm wondering if there's a way around this - perhaps recording the output as it's played silently, for playback later? Or something more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now `AVSpeechSynthesizer`  does not support this . There in no way get the audio file using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` . I tried this few weeks ago for one of my apps and found out that it is not possible , Also nothing has changed for  `AVSpeechSynthesizer` in iOS 8.

I too thought of recording the sound as it is being played , but there are so many flaws with that approach like user might be using headphones, the system sound might be low or mute , it might catch other external sound, so its not advisable to go with that approach.

Answer (score 24):

This is finally possible, in iOS 13 `AVSpeechSynthesizer` now has  [write(_:toBufferCallback:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer/3141659-write):

```swift
let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "test 123")
utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en")
var output: AVAudioFile?

synthesizer.write(utterance) { (buffer: AVAudioBuffer) in
   guard let pcmBuffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
      fatalError("unknown buffer type: \(buffer)")
   }
   if pcmBuffer.frameLength == 0 {
     // done
   } else {
     // append buffer to file
     if output == nil { 
       output = AVAudioFile(
         forWriting: URL(fileURLWithPath: "test.caf"), 
         settings: pcmBuffer.format.settings, 
         commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16, 
         interleaved: false) 
     }
     output?.write(from: pcmBuffer)
   } 
}
```

Comment: When executing under Mac OS 10.15 the callback is never being called. The synthesizer just pronounces the text instead.

Comment: I just bumped into that on 10.15 too, any change/workaround @vasily ? oh well back to NSSpeechSynthesizer ‍♂️

Comment: @glotcha No resolution so far

Comment: This is still a bug in macOS. I've raised a bug report via Feedback Assistant.

Comment: I've raised this now as a DTS incident with Apple, they're investigating.

Comment: With Big Sur 11.2 Beta, the callbacks are now being received. However, there is only ever one callback; and the frameLength for that callback is never zero! I've fed this information back to Apple.

Comment: I've today received the following response from Apple: "On macOS, there is only one callback made with all the audio data.

You can know when the speech is finished, because the didFinishSpeaking callback is called when processing is done."

Comment: With BigSur 11.1.x, the int32 audio data is received, but would appear to be an approximate square wave; you can hear the audio, but is is very heavily distorted. Raised with DTS...

Comment: any solution yet? I am using Xamarin.IOS and the same happens, the App crashes in "WriteUtterance" and the callback is never executed. 1.5 years have passed... Has at least someone found a workaround?

Comment: Can't play the  output file use AVAudioPlayer

Comment: For me on macOS 12.2 the callback is still never being called. :/

Comment: Note that the synthesizer instance should not be created locally in the func. It should either be a member of a class or global, otherwise it is released before having the chance to start synthesizing and the callback is never called.

Answer (score 2):

I have this working now on both iOS (17.1.1) and macOS (14.0) with Xcode 15.0.1. This is largely just a minor tweak to the [answer by @Jan Berkel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58118583/668253) that helps avoid the “square wave distortion” and crash reported by comments to that answer. Referring to @Jan Berkel’s answer, I found that in the call to the AVAudioFile initializer the commonFormat: argument should be .pcmFormatFloat32 in order to work on iOS and macOS, while it should be .pcmFormatInt16 to work without crash when run under simulator (don’t ask me why—this is just an observation;-).

Here is the relevant code that works on macOS and iOS device (but crashes in simulator during `output?.write(from: pcmBuffer)`):

```
output = try AVAudioFile(
   forWriting: url,
   settings: pcmBuffer.format.settings,
   commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32,    // works on iOS device and on macOS, but crashes in simulator during self.output?.write(from: pcmBuffer)
   interleaved: false)
```

And here is the code that works on the simulator in Xcode (but produces noise on macOS and iOS device):

```
output = try AVAudioFile(
   forWriting: url,
   settings: pcmBuffer.format.settings,
   commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16,    // this produces noise on macOS and iOS device, but works in simulator
   interleaved: false)
```

That’s it. That’s the only tweak I had to do to the answer by @Jan Berkel. Looking at comments to that answer, it is clear that there are various pitfalls in making this work, most notably that one must make sure that the speech synthesizer is not released until the file has been generated, and being able to receive callbacks. So let me post example code that shows how the answer can be used to create an audio file with speech synthesis, and then play it back — making sure the speech synthesizer and the audio player are not released too early, and are able to receive the various callbacks. This code example uses "Swift async-await" in order to handle the callbacks, but that could of course be accomplished many other ways. This code has been tested on macOS, iOS device, and iOS simulator (with the given caveats).

```
import Foundation
import AVFAudio

let url : URL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask,appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appending(path: "test123.caf", directoryHint: .notDirectory)
let maker = SpokenAudioFileMaker()
let player = SpokenAudioFilePlayer()

func exampleOfUse() async {
    do {
        try await maker.makeAudioFile(text: "test 123", url: url)
        print("Made audio file")
        try await player.play(cafAudioFileUrl: url)
        print("Played audio file")
    } catch {
        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

class SpokenAudioFileMaker : NSObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    let synthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer() // hold on to this object to prevent it from being released before file has been generated
    var output : AVAudioFile? = nil
    // for async-await:
    var audioMakerContinuation : CheckedContinuation<(success:Bool, dummy:Int), Error>? = nil
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        synthesizer.delegate = self
    }
    
    func makeAudioFile(text:String, url:URL) async throws {
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: text)
        _ = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({ (continuation:CheckedContinuation<(success:Bool, dummy:Int), Error>) in
            audioMakerContinuation = continuation
            //
            synthesizer.write(utterance) { (buffer: AVAudioBuffer) in
                guard let pcmBuffer = buffer as? AVAudioPCMBuffer else {
                    fatalError("unknown buffer type: \(buffer)")
                }
                if pcmBuffer.frameLength == 0 {
                    // the loop has completed - done.
                } else {
                    do {
                        // append buffer for this range of the utterance to file
                        if self.output == nil {     // essential to avoid file being overridden for each range of the utterance
                            self.output = try AVAudioFile(
                                forWriting: url,
                                settings: pcmBuffer.format.settings,
                                commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32,    // this works on iOS device and on macOS, but crashes in simulator during self.output?.write(from: pcmBuffer)
                                // commonFormat: .pcmFormatInt16,    // this produces noise on iOS device, but works in simulator
                                interleaved: false)
                        }
                        try self.output?.write(from: pcmBuffer)
                    } catch {
                        fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    
    // MARK: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate

    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("speechSynthesizer didFinish utterance: \(utterance.speechString)")
        self.output = nil
        audioMakerContinuation?.resume(returning: (success: true, dummy:0))
    }
    
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, willSpeakRangeOfSpeechString characterRange: NSRange, utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        print("speechSynthesizer will speak range...")
    }
}

class SpokenAudioFilePlayer: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    private var player : AVAudioPlayer?
    // for async-await:
    var audioPlayerContinuation : CheckedContinuation<(success:Bool, dummy:Int), Error>? = nil

    func play(cafAudioFileUrl:URL) async throws {
        let audioData = try Data(contentsOf: cafAudioFileUrl)
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(data:audioData, fileTypeHint:"caf")
        player?.delegate = self
        _ = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation({ (continuation:CheckedContinuation<(success:Bool, dummy:Int), Error>) in
            audioPlayerContinuation = continuation
            //
            player?.play()
        })
    }

    // MARK: AVAudioPlayerDelegate
    
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        print("audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying")
        audioPlayerContinuation?.resume(returning: (success: true, dummy:0))
    }

    func audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        audioPlayerContinuation?.resume(returning: (success: false, dummy:0))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use OSX to prepare AIFF files (or, maybe, some OSX-based service) via NSSpeechSynthesizer method
startSpeakingString:toURL:

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by some comments of @Jan's answer, unfortunately `AVSpeechSynthesizer` doesn't work on macOS. All other search results are pointed to this question.

Also as pointed out by the comments, `NSSpeechSynthesizer` from `import AppKit` still works, although it's marked as deprecated: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer

I tested the following code on macOS Ventura and it works as expected. Basically you need to find out a string from `NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices` instead of `AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()`, and you need to use the `didFinish` delegate to make sure writing is done (not included in my test code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizerdelegate/1448538-speechsynthesizer).

It's a bit disappointing that we have to use legacy API to implement such basic feature, but I believe they are calling the same thing internally.

```
func test() throws {
    NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices.forEach { print($0) }
    guard let synthesizer = NSSpeechSynthesizer(voice: NSSpeechSynthesizer.VoiceName(rawValue: "com.apple.voice.enhanced.en-US.Evan")) else {
        print("Voice not found")
        throw CoreError.unexpectedNil
    }
    synthesizer.rate = 0.4
    let result = synthesizer.startSpeaking("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. lol", to: URL(fileURLWithPath: "test.aiff"))
    print(result)
    sleep(1)
}
```