# Is there a way to record all the sound that is outputted by the app?

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit

What I am actually trying to do is generate a sound-wave for the audio produced by AVSpeechSynthesizer. As id does not have an interface to save the audio file i am trying to record the sound generated by the app altogether.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVSpeechSynthesizer output as file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965601/avspeechsynthesizer-output-as-file)

Answer (score 3):

On iOS, you can only use the AVSpeechSynthesizer to output directly to the speakers. For some reason, they do not allow you to pipe it into anything else. This is why AudioKit's speech synthesizer is only implement on the macOS side of things

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manage the recording process with Apples [Audio Unit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiounit#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007295) Framework but it can be very complicated and i have never tried it.
But i think this is the only Framework in the IOS SDK that can play and record audio at the same time.