# OBJC AVSpeechUtterance writeUtterance how?

Tags: objective-c, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

I am trying to create a TTS to file in Objc.
Since iOS13 can write it to a file.
But I'm stuck with writeUtterance:toBufferCallback.

Do someone has an exemple with this function in objc?

`[synth speakUtterance:utterance];`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58118583/402223) probably answers your question.

Comment: In swift ok, but all my code is in objc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Referring to the potential answer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58118583/402223), this would be the Objective-C implementation

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:@"test 123"];
AVSpeechSynthesisVoice *voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-US"];
[utterance setVoice:voice];

__block AVAudioFile *output = nil;

[synthesizer writeUtterance:utterance
           toBufferCallback:^(AVAudioBuffer * _Nonnull buffer) {
    AVAudioPCMBuffer *pcmBuffer = (AVAudioPCMBuffer*)buffer;
    if (!pcmBuffer) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
        return;
    }
    if (pcmBuffer.frameLength != 0) {
        //append buffer to file
        if (output == nil) {
            output = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForWriting:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"test.caf"]
                                                settings:pcmBuffer.format.settings
                                            commonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatInt16
                                             interleaved:NO error:nil];
        }
        [output writeFromBuffer:pcmBuffer error:nil];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Great! Thank you! Works perfect. Now I get it.