# How do I save tts voice to mp3 in swift?

Tags: swift

I saved the tts as caf using the link below as source
but i want to know how to save as mp3 not caf file

[AVSpeechSynthesizer output as file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965601/avspeechsynthesizer-output-as-file)

Comment: Why don't you help yourself by making another search for converting caf into mp3?

Comment: Hint: Look for a third-party library

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an mp3 using iOS native APIs (because of copyright issues). iOS can read an mp3 but it cannot make one.